# Trouble in the second order ordinary differential equations with second oder coupled iterm

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving

I ran into a system of ordinary differential equations of second order and was puzzled by it for a few days.
[image]
It was originally easy to solve, but because the coupling term is second order, it cannot be solved directly by Mma.
Here's the code I tried

```
eqs = {q[1]''[t] + q[1][t] -Sin[Pi t] (9.81 - q[1]''[t] Sin[ Pi t] - q[2]''[t] Sin[ 2*Pi t]) == 0 ,
  q[2]''[t] + q[2][t] - Sin[2*Pi t] (9.81 - q[1]''[t] Sin[ Pi t] - q[2]''[t] Sin[ 2*Pi t]) == 0}
int = {q[1][0] == 0, q[2][0] == 0, q[1]'[0] == 0, q[2]'[0] == 0};
var = {q[1], q[2]};
exp = eqs~Join~int;
NDSolve[exp, var, {t, 0, 1}]
```

> Infinity::indet: Indeterminate expression 0. ComplexInfinity encountered.
>
> Infinity::indet: Indeterminate expression 0. ComplexInfinity ComplexInfinity encountered.
>
> General::stop: Further output of Infinity::indet will be suppressed during this calculation.
>
> Infinity::indet: Indeterminate expression 0. ComplexInfinity ComplexInfinity encountered.
>
> NDSolve::ndnum: Encountered non-numerical value for a derivative at t == 0.`.
> I'm not sure if this system can be solved with mma, and I don't know how to solve it. I really hope you can help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because when transforming the system to the standard form required by ODE solver of `NDSolve`, a removable singularity is generated at $t=0$. (For more information check [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/158519/1871). ) There're at least 3 solutions for this problem. The easiest one is add `SolveDelayed -> True`:

```
NDSolveValue[exp, var, {t, 0, 1}, SolveDelayed -> True]
```

Or use a small number as starting point instead of $0$:

```
eps = 10^-3;
intappro = {q[1][eps] == 0, q[2][eps] == 0, q[1]'[eps] == 0, q[2]'[eps] == 0};
NDSolveValue[{eqs, intappro}, var, {t, eps, 1}]
```

Or use the asymptotic solution near $t=0$ as the initial condition:

```
asysol = AsymptoticDSolveValue[exp, var, {t, 0, 5}]

asyexpr = {q[1]@t, q[2]@t} == asysol // Thread

newic = {asyexpr, D[asyexpr, t]} /. t -> eps
sol = NDSolveValue[{eqs, newic}, var, {t, eps, 1}]

sol // ListLinePlot
```

[image]

Comment: I almost thought this equation was impossible to solve, and I really wanted to solve it myself. It seems that I am not familiar with the NDSolve solver and the process of solving differential equations. Thank you very much for your help and make me saw this problem clearly.