# What's the solver behind Method -> {“EquationSimplification” -> “MassMatrix”}

Tags: differential-equations, implementation-details, undocumented

Related: [What's behind Method -> {“EquationSimplification” -> “Residual”}](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/136114/whats-behind-method-equationsimplification-residual)

By reading the document carefully, I've learnt that there are 3 possible options in "EquationSimplification" for DAE systems: `Solve`, `Residual` and `MassMatrix`. `Solve` and `Residual` have been explained in the above answer detailedly. As far as I understand, `Residual` converts the DAE system into the residual form $f(t, x, \dot{x}) = 0$ and solves the system with `IDA` from Sundials.

On the other hand, `MassMatrix` converts the system into the mass matrix form $M.\dot{x} = f(t, x)$. But I cannot find in the documentation which solver will be used (maybe I missed something?). Can anyone explain what's the solver behind it?

I tried some examples with `` NDSolve`ProcessEquations `` with `"EquationSimplification" -> "MassMatrix"` and `"TimeIntegration" -> "StateSpace"`. The `NumericalFunction` behind them are different. My guess is that it does not use the method `StateSpace`. It probably uses some ODE solvers, since other softwares like Matlab does use ODE solvers to solve DAE problems in mass matrix form?

Comment: " I cannot find in the documentation which solver will be used (maybe I missed something?) " I fail, too. The introduction for `"MassMatrix"` in the document seems to be quite brief, that's (at least partly) the reason why I avoided talking about this option in the linked answer. (I doubt if this option will be automatically chosen by `NDSolve` in any cases? We need to explicitly set `“EquationSimplification” -> “MassMatrix”` even for the 2 examples in the document. ) Hope someone knowledgable can give an answer.

Comment: @xzczd I tried some examples with `NDSolve`ProcessEquations` with `“EquationSimplification” -> “MassMatrix”` and `"TimeIntegration"->"StateSpace"`. The `NumericalFunction` behind them are different. My guess is that it does not use the method `StateSpace`. It probably uses some ODE solvers, since other softwares like Matlab does use ODE solvers to solve DAE problems in mass matrix form?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I tried some examples with `` NDSolve`ProcessEquations `` with `"EquationSimplification" -> "MassMatrix"` and `"TimeIntegration" -> "StateSpace"`. The `NumericalFunction` behind them are different.

I'm not sure how you checked their equivalence. (Notice `` Experimental`NumericalFunction `` involves temporal variables so you cannot check the equivalence with `===`. ) But `Method -> {EquationSimplification -> MassMatrix, TimeIntegration -> StateSpace}` seems to be the answer. This can be checked with

```
test[method_] := 
 NDSolveValue[{{x'[t] + y'[t] == Sin[t] - z'[t], 
                y'[t] + z'[t] == Sin[t] + x[t], 
                x'[t] + z'[t] == y[t] + Cos[t]}, 
               {x[0] == 1, y[0] == 1, z[0] == 1}}, 
              x, {t, 0, 1}, 
              Method -> {EquationSimplification -> MassMatrix, 
                         TimeIntegration -> method}]

test[Automatic] === test[StateSpace]
(* True *)
```

Further check shows the following methods can also be combined with `MassMatrix` method, but none of them reproduces the default output:

```
methodlist = {{"DoubleStep", Method -> Automatic}, 
              {"Extrapolation", Method -> Automatic}, 
              {"FixedStep", Method -> Automatic}, 
             "LinearlyImplicitEuler", 
             "LinearlyImplicitMidpoint", 
             "LinearlyImplicitModifiedMidpoint", 
             "ImplicitRungeKutta"};

test /@ methodlist // Map@SameAs@test@Automatic
(* {False, False, False, False, False, False, False} *)
```