# Solve matrix of ODEs using NDSolve

Tags: differential-equations, matrix

I wish to solve an ordinary differential equation of matrices. This is a minimal working example I am working towards nonlinear equations. The accuracy of the solution is important for me. I have hit two problems.

1. Why does Mathematica have to set up differential-algebraic equations?
2. For accuracy how can I use something like the options;
   `InterpolationOrder->All, Method->"ImplicitRungeKutta"`?

I generate a set of three differential equations, their initial conditions and then go on to solve them using `NDSolve`

```
ClearAll[d, v, t];
ff0 = {10, 15, 22};
mm0 = {1, 2, 2.5};
dr = {0.001, 0.01, 0.015};
nn = Length[ff0];
SeedRandom[123];
R0 = Orthogonalize[RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {nn, nn}]];
R = Orthogonalize[RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {nn, nn}]];
cc = R0 . DiagonalMatrix[2 dr 2 \[Pi] ff0 ] . Transpose[R0];
mm = R . DiagonalMatrix[mm0] . Transpose[R];
kk = R . DiagonalMatrix[(2 \[Pi] ff0)^2 mm0] . Transpose[R];

(* Initial conditions *)
dic = ConstantArray[0, nn]; dic[[1]] = 1;
vic = ConstantArray[0, nn];

(* Solve differential equations *)
te = 30;
{disp, vel} = {d, v} /. First@NDSolve [{
     d'[t] == v[t],
     mm . v'[t] + cc . v[t] + kk . d[t] == 0,
     d[0] == dic, v[0] == vic},
    {d, v},
    {t, 0, te}]
```

This does work and gives me answers but the following message appears

```
NDSolve::ntdvdae: Cannot solve to find an explicit formula for the derivatives. NDSolve will try solving the system as differential-algebraic equations.
```

Why is Mathematica doing this?

If I try for high accuracy using

```
(* Solve differential equations with high accuracy *)
te = 30;
{disp, vel} = {d, v} /. First@NDSolve [{
     d'[t] == v[t],
     mm . v'[t] + cc . v[t] + kk . d[t] == 0,
     d[0] == dic, v[0] == vic},
    {d, v},
    {t, 0, te},
    InterpolationOrder -> All,
    Method -> "ImplicitRungeKutta"]
```

Then I get a string of messages with these being key

```
NDSolve::ntdvdae: Cannot solve to find an explicit formula for the derivatives. NDSolve will try solving the system as differential-algebraic equations.

NDSolve::nodae: The method NDSolve`ImplicitRungeKutta is not currently implemented to solve differential-algebraic equations. Use Method -> Automatic instead.
```

I am using version 14.0.0 for windows.

Thanks for any help

Comment: Use `mm1 = Inverse[mm]; sol = NDSolve[{d'[t] == v[t], 
   v'[t] + mm1 . (cc . v[t]) + mm1 . (kk . d[t]) == 0, d[0] == dic, 
   v[0] == vic}, {d, v}, {t, 0, te}, Method -> "ImplicitRungeKutta"]`

Comment: 1. Seems that the pre-processor of `NDSolve` isn't strong enough. This system can be solved with `MassMatrix` method to avoid calculating `Inverse[mm]` in principle (`MassMatrix` sometimes works better than `Residual`, and it works with some of the ODE solvers: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/277822/1871 ), but `NDSolve` just can't do it when `v` and `d` are implicit vectors. The only solution I can think out at the moment is to use explicit vector to represent `v` and `d`, the pre-processing will be slower then, but at least we can now adjust the ODE solver freely.

Comment: 2. Are you sure you need `ImplicitRungeKutta`? According to my limited experience, setting a proper `MaxStepSize` is usually quite enough to achieve good accuracy.

Comment: @AlexTrounev Thanks that does work. I will have to think if this is applicable when I go forward to nonlinear systems.

Comment: @Hugh It could be better to show your nonlinear system.

Comment: @xzczd I will investigate controlling the step size. I was following the very successful output from [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/225444/12558)