# NDSolve giving a wrong solution

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, numerical-value

Consider the ODE
$$\frac{y'y}{1+\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{1+ y'^2}}=-x.$$

Using

```
NDSolve[{-x==y'[x] y[x]/(1+Sqrt[1+(y'[x])^2]/2), y[0] ==3}, y, {x,-7,7}]
```

and plotting leads to the two solutions (some warnings near the boundaries)

$$y(x) = \sqrt{6^2 - x^2} - 3$$
and
$$y(x) = \sqrt{2^2 - x^2} + 1.$$

But only the latter one is a valid solution!
No matter which 'Method' I tried, always got a completely wrong solution.
Except using

```
Method -> {"EquationSimplification" -> "Residual"}
```

Why is that?

*Note:* As pointed out in an answer below, fixing the value in `x=0` is critical, since $y'$ vanishes here. But using other starting values like `y[Sqrt[3]]=2` the problem **gets even worse** since one branch is now completely wrong everywhere and the other branch is correct only in a small area.

Comment: Look at your ODE: y^[x]== -x[t](1+Sqrt[1+y'[t]^2]) / y[t] Note that you divide y y. As soon as y[t] becomes small the tangent is nearly vertical and the calculation explodes. This happens near x==+/- 2

Comment: Right, as indicated by the warnings. But that's no reason to construct a false solution far away from these points.

Comment: @fwgb If we use `Solve[-x == y'[x] y[x]/(1 + Sqrt[1 + (y'[x])^2]/2), y'[x]]`, then we get 2 branches of `y'[x]`. 'NDSolve[]` calculates two branches with initial condition  `y[0]=3` for `{x,-2,6}` and `{x,-6,2}`. With option `"EquationSimplification" -> "Residual" ` we solve system of algebraic equations and get solution as a combination of two branches.

Comment: Sure, but the branches you get are wrong in $[2,6]$ and $[-6,-2]$, respectively. Their combination although is correct.

Comment: @fwgb Don't forget this is numerical solution (not actually my solution, but from `NDSolve`). And as numerical solution two branches are not wrong.

Comment: Numerical or not, algorithm should check if its result is valid or not.

Comment: @fwgb Actually it is you job to check and validate result. Numerical algorithm could not be so complicated. Maybe in a future when some AI will be implemented.

Comment: Could'nt disagree more. Its the easiest thing to check a solution. Finding might be difficult.

Comment: @fwgb , if you do `red = Reduce[(eqs[[1]] /. {y[x] -> y, y'[x] -> ys}), ys, Reals] `  you see, that you have to switch solutions at x = zero.

Comment: Nevertheless what NDSolve returns for the other half is wrong

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason for that behavior seems to be a big logical bug in `NDSolve`.
During calculation it seems to treat expressions like:
`y==Sqrt[x]` and `y^2==x` as the same. But, as every user knows here, they're not!

As confirmation, take your particular example:
Multiplying by the denominator gives
$$-x\left(1-\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{1+(y'(x))^2}\right)=y'(x) y(x).$$
Squaring both sides stupidly and solving for $y'(x)$ creates two branches

```
NDSolve[{y'[x]==(4 x y[x]+Sqrt[3 x^4 + 4 x^2 y[x]^2])/(x^2 - 4 y[x]^2) , y[0]==3}, y, {x,-6,6}]
```

and

```
NDSolve[{y'[x]==(4 x y[x]-Sqrt[3 x^4 + 4 x^2 y[x]^2])/(x^2 - 4 y[x]^2) , y[0]==3}, y, {x,-6,6}]
```

These are indeed exactly the branches `NDSolve` does provide, although none is valid.

Even worse, although being fundamental, it does not check the solutions.
This would require just an extra line of code in the algorithm as it already uses the tuples $(x_i,y(x_i),y'(x_i)$. Just plug them into the equation and check if its true or false (up to some numerical error).

**Edit:** `NDSolve` needs to transform the equation to some kind of standard form, which is controlled by `EquationSimplification`. There are three possible options for this method: `MassMatrix`, `Residual` and `Solve` which is the default. The latter transforms the equation into a form with no derivatives on one side. The system is then solved with an *ordinary differential* equation solver.
When `Residual` is chosen all the non-zero terms in the equation are just moved to one side and then solved with a *differential algebraic* equation solver.
This is the reason the result is correct in this case as it doesn't use `Solve` which is buggy here.

Comment: (+1) You're right as far as the source of the problem (that solvers tend to convert equations to polynomial algebra over $\Bbb C$), and each branch is valid for the general ODE over a restricted domain. I'm pretty sure that, given the `NDSolve` framework, it's more than an extra line of code to switch branches in the middle of an integration. There's also an expense checking each step that might be more than the gain.

Comment: @MichaelE2 But there is no need to check every point in the branch, just a few to check if its valid at all. That's not really expensive.

Comment: Then you're not trying to switch branches when necessary, just determine the branch for the initial step(s).

Comment: Another way to look at it is that the sort of checking you're talking about is in effect what `Method -> {"EquationSimplification" -> "Residual"}` does.

Comment: This might help here: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/136114/whats-behind-method-equationsimplification-residual

Comment: @darksun Nice find. ´NDSolve´ seems to use ´Solve´ first to bring the problem into the form $y'(x)=...$. This goes wrong here. Afterwards, applying a numerical scheme to solve the new ODE's for each branch.

Answer (score 9):

#### The general problem

In using `NDSolve` to solve first-order IVPs, there are basically two ways to set up the ODE:

```
y'[x] == f[x, y[x]]     (* explicit form *)
F[x, y[x], y'[x]] == 0  (* implicit form *)
```

Most numerical solvers require the problem to be specified in explicit form.  In *Mathematica*, there is only one solver that works with the implicit form, [IDA](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveIDAMethod.html), and it is restricted to machine precision.  Since it is easy to convert the implicit form to an explicit second-order ODE by differentiating with respect to `x`, perhaps there has not been much pressure to develop implicit-form solvers.

In *Mathematica*, you can request that a solution be attempted in either form with the `Method` option:

```
Method -> {"EquationSimplification" -> "Solve"}    (* explicit *)
Method -> {"EquationSimplification" -> "Residual"} (* implicit *)
```

With the `"Solve"` method, which is the default, `NDSolve` calls `Solve` to convert an ODE to explicit form.  An equation given in implicit form may have multiple solutions, and if so, `NDSolve` will integrate each one separately.  That is what happens in the OP's example.  Further, `NDSolve` is set up to integrate the separate explict-form ODEs independently and cannot combine them, which is what is required in the OP's case (see [@BobHanlon's answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/235095/ndsolve-giving-a-wrong-solution/235103#235103)).

Now `Solve`'s issue of [genericity](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/17127/what-is-the-difference-between-reduce-and-solve) plays an important role here.  In the OP's case, it returns solutions that are each valid over certain domains and invalid in other nonempty regions, including ones we want to integrate over.  `Reduce` is much more careful and correctly analyzes the OP's system.  One can make `Solve` use `Reduce` with the option `Method -> Reduce`, but it still returns two separate solutions, each valid one side of `x == 0`.  Further it returns `ConditionalExpression`, which `NDSolve` chokes on (and gives a "non-numerical" `NDSolve::ndnum` error at the initial condition during [the `ProcessEquations` phase](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveStateData.html#1805463009)). `ConditionalExpression` was introduced pretty late, in V8, and perhaps not enough requests to have `NDSolve` handle it properly have been made to WRI.

OTOH, the `"Residual"` method solves the ODE implicitly at each step.  Since both solutions are valid simultaneously only at `x == 0`, it will find the right branch once `NDSolve` takes a step.  This computes the correct solution, which the OP mentions.  The only drawback is that only one integration method is available and only in machine precision.

It does seem it would be an easy thing in the `` NDSolve`ProcessEquations `` stage to check that the original implicit-form ODE is satisfied by the explicit forms at the initial condition.  That wouldn't catch the  problem in the example at `y[0] == 3`, at which point both explicit forms satisfy the implicit-form ODE, but it would catch the problem at `y[1] == 2`.  Another issue with the solutions returned by `Solve` is that the explicit formula for `y'[x]` needs to switch branches to the other solution returned by `Solve` when integration crosses `x == 0`.  Switching branches is not something `NDSolve` is set up to do nor does it seem to me to be an easy programming fix, since each solution is integrated independently.  Some ways to do this are given below, but all require the user to prepare the `NDSolve` call.  None are done automatically by `NDSolve`, which would be desirable.

Finally, what should the user expect?  For a long time now in scientific computation, the user has been expected to set up the numerical integration of differential equations.  This seems still to be the case in MATLAB and NumPy.  I don't know Maple well enough to comment.  The general philosophy of *Mathematica* has been to make everything automatic as much as possible.  *Mathematica* also has tended to use generically true solutions instead of a more rigorous restriction.  These are somewhat in conflict here, since the generic methods of `Solve` are a source of the issue with the `NDSolve` solutions.  On the other hand, to have everything be automatic is not so much a Wolfram goal as a guiding principle.  The Q&As on this site show that `Automatic` does not always get the job done.  The user often has to understand the problem, know what solvers are available, prepare the input accordingly, and call the solver with the right options.  For an implicit-form IVP, the user should be aware that there can be a problem with solving for `y'[x]`.  They should also be aware that there are standard ways of dealing with implicit-form ODEs:

- using an implicit solver like IDA, called when `"Residual"` is invoked;
- differentiating to raise the order;
- solving for `y'[x]` explicitly, the default `"Solve"` method.

I'll reiterate that I think it's reasonable to expect `NDSolve` to check that an explicit-form satisfies the original implicit-form ODE at the initial condition.  While the user can check the results of `NDSolve` after the fact, in cases like the IVP `y[1] == 2`, it would prevent an extraneous integration.

#### The OP's examples

The explicit solutions for `y'[x]` we get for the OP's ODE have two branches for `x < 0` and two for `x > 0`.
The two solutions result from the (algebraic) rationalization of the ODE, which introduces the possibility of extraneous solutions. In fact, the solution set consists of four connected components, two for the interval `x < 0` and two for `x > 0`.  Each solution returned by `Solve` is valid over one interval but not over both.  However, we can transform them into one correct and one incorrect solution by `Simplify[..., x > 0]`, but that's hardly a general technique, I think.

*Workaround #1*

The OP's discovery:

```
ode = -x == y'[x] y[x]/(1 + Sqrt[1 + (y'[x])^2]/2);

ListLinePlot[
 NDSolveValue[{ode, y[0] == 3}, y, {x, -7, 7}, 
  Method -> {"EquationSimplification" -> "Residual"}],
 PlotRange -> All
 ]
```

[image]

*Workaround #2*

**Differentiating the ODE** raises the order but results in one for which there is a unique explicit form.  You have to use the ODE to solve for the initial condition for `y'[0]`.

```
sol = NDSolve[{D[ode, x], y[0] == 3, y'[0] == 0}, y, {x, -7, 7}]
```

*Workaround #3*

Use the **correct explicit form**, constructed from the correct branches for `x <> 0`:

```
ode2 = y'[x] == 
   Piecewise[{
    {(4 x y[x] - Sqrt[3 x^4 + 4 x^2 y[x]^2])/(x^2 - 4 y[x]^2), x < 0}}, 
    (4 x y[x] + Sqrt[3 x^4 + 4 x^2 y[x]^2])/(x^2 - 4 y[x]^2)];

sol = NDSolve[{ode2, y[0] == 3}, y, {x, -7, 7}]
```

*Workaround #4*

There are problems with our algebraic notation and its relation to algebraic functions.
Applying the assumption `x > 0` **alters the branch-cut selection when simplifying** the solutions returned by `Solve` so that one of them is correct. In other words, this gives a simpler formula for `y'[x]` that is equivalent to Workaround #3.

```
sol = NDSolve[{#, y[0] == 3} /. Rule -> Equal, y, {x, -7, 7}] & /@
  Assuming[x > 0,
   Select[Simplify@Solve[ode, y'[x]], 
    ode /. # /. {y[x] -> 1, x -> 1.`20} &]
   ] // Apply[Join]
```

*Workaround #5*

The `Solve` option **`Method -> Reduce`** produces correct solutions in the form of a `ConditionalExpression`.
To get a method that checks and chooses the correct branch of an ODE that implicitly defines `y'[x]`, the user would have to do their own preprocessing.
The following is a way in which `rhs[]` selects the branch that satisfies the original ODE by converting the conditional expressions into a single `Piecewise` function.  The conditions are converted from equations `a == b` to a comparison `Abs[a-b] < 10^-8`.  I had to add the value at the branch point `x == 0` manually.

In other words, this checks `y'[x]` at each step and selects the correct branch for the step.  It will thus automatically switch branches when needed, at `x == 0` in the OP's problem.  It is worth pointing out that this fixes a problem arising from rationalization of the ODE that introduces extraneous branches.  It is possible for an implicit-form ODE to have multiple valid branches.  The method below will combine them all (if the solutions have the `ConditionalExpression` form), which should be considered an error, although it might still accidentally produce a correct solution.  For the OP's ODE, it does the right thing.

```
ClearAll[rhs];
rhs[x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ] = Piecewise[
   yp /. Solve[ode /. {y[x] -> y, y'[x] -> yp}, yp, 
       Method -> Reduce] /. ConditionalExpression -> List /. 
    Equal -> (Abs[#1 - #2] < 10^-8 &),
   0 (* y'[0] == 0 *)];

sol = NDSolve[{y'[x] == rhs[x, y[x]], y[0] == 3}, y, {x, -7, 7}]
```

Here is a very hacky way to fix up the result of the internal `Solve` result.  It is achieved through a sequence of viral `UpValues` for `$tag` that rewrites a `ConditionalExpression` solution into a `Piecewise` solution like the one above.

```
opts = Options@Solve;
SetOptions[Solve, Method -> Reduce];
Block[{ConditionalExpression = $tag, $tag},
 $tag /: Rule[v_, $tag[a_, b_]] := $tag[v, a, b];
 $tag /: {$tag[v_, a_, b_]} := $tag[List, v, a, b];
 $tag /: call : {$tag[List, v_, __] ..} := {{v -> 
     Piecewise[
      Unevaluated[call][[All, -2 ;;]] /. $tag -> List /. 
       Equal -> (Abs[#1 - #2] < 1*^-8 &)]}};
 sol = NDSolve[{ode, y[0] == 3}, y, {x, -7, 7}]
 ]
SetOptions[Solve, opts];
```

*How to see what `Solve` does inside `NDSolve`*

If you want to see what happens internally, you can use `Trace`.  `NDSolve` uses `Solve` to solve the ODE for the highest order derivative, if it can, and uses the solution(s) to construct the integral(s).  This shows the `Solve` call and its return value:

```
Trace[
 NDSolve[
  {ode, y[0] == 3},
  y, {x, -7, 7}],
 _Solve,
 TraceForward -> True,
 TraceInternal -> True
 ]
```

Comment: No, you can use any starting point other than $0$ (e.g. y(1)=2) and get the same result. That's not the problem.

Comment: @fwgb The problem still seems to be `x == 0`.

Comment: No, if you use 'NDSolve' in an intervall without $0$ (e.g. '{x,0.5,7}') you get the same result. That's not the problem.

Comment: @fwgb Ah, I think we were talking about different things...

Comment: Regarding you're second answer. I have the same feeling. But, to be honest, an equation solver not checking its solutions (although it requires just a single line of code) is scandalous. Having in mind that this software is in development for 33 years.

Comment: @fwgb But in your example, if it checked at `x == 0`, both solutions seem valid. Personally I don't understand why didn't use `y[1] == 2` as your example. `x == 0` is a problem no matter what, but a different problem, where the ODE solution switches branches (as they are returned by `Solve`).

Comment: Okay, $x=0$ might cause other problems. I could have used $y(1)=2$ to make it simpler, but the original problem remains.

Comment: Regarding the massively extended answer: Well done! Good workarounds. In particular the confirmation of the issue in `Solve`. You might want to use parts from it to answer this as well: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/235185/incorrect-result-by-dsolve

Comment: @fwgb Thank you. I had worked out most of it a couple days ago, but I don't have a lot of time.  I'll see if can get to your other question sometime soon.

Answer (score 3):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

sol = DSolve[{-x == y'[x] y[x]/(1 + Sqrt[1 + (y'[x])^2]/2), y[0] == 3}, y, 
   x] // Quiet

(* {{y -> Function[{x}, Sqrt[5 - x^2 + 2 Sqrt[4 - x^2]]]}, 
    {y -> Function[{x}, Sqrt[45 - x^2 - 6 Sqrt[36 - x^2]]]}} *)

FunctionDomain[y[x] /. sol[[1]], x]

(* -2 <= x <= 2 *)
```

The first solution is valid for `-2 <= x <= 2`

```
{-x == y'[x] y[x]/(1 + Sqrt[1 + (y'[x])^2]/2), y[0] == 3} /. sol[[1]] // 
 Simplify[#, -2 <= x <= 2] &

(* {True, True} *)

FunctionDomain[y[x] /. sol[[2]], x]

(* -6 <= x <= 6 *)
```

The second solution is true for `x == 0`

```
{-x == y'[x] y[x]/(1 + Sqrt[1 + (y'[x])^2]/2), y[0] == 3} /. sol[[2]] // 
 FullSimplify[#, -6 <= x <= 6] &

(* {x == 0, True} *)

Plot[Evaluate[y[x] /. sol], {x, -6, 6},
 PlotLegends -> Placed[Automatic, {.75, .2}]]
```

[image]

For the numeric solution, restrict the domain to `{- 2, 2}`

```
soln = NDSolve[{-x == y'[x] y[x]/(1 + Sqrt[1 + (y'[x])^2]/2), y[0] == 3}, 
    y, {x, -2, 2}] // Quiet;
```

The numeric solutions are valid in different portions of the domain

```
Plot[Evaluate[y[x] /. soln], {x, -2, 2},
 PlotRange -> {0, 3.1},
 PlotLegends -> Placed[Automatic, {.7, .5}]]
```

[image]

Comment: Surely, the second function is true in $0$, since $y(0)=3$ was assumed. The solutions are split into two symmetric parts (1&2). In that regard, even both are wrong. (Except restricting the domain properly). Although a valid one can be deduced from it.

Answer (score 0):

Start at

```
Plot[Evaluate[y[x] /. sol], {x, -2, 2}, 
 PlotLegends -> Placed[Automatic, {.75, .2}], PlotPoints -> 1600, 
 ImageSize -> Large, PlotRange -> Full]
```

[image: Plot of the DSolve solutions]

What is in the differential equation?

$$\frac{′}{1+\sqrt{1+′^2}}=−$$

1. This a differential equation of the implicit type.
2. It is an differential equation of first order ${y,y'}$.
3. It is a nonlinear differential equation.
4. It is given in the form of a quotient, so there is need to investigate for singularities of the denominator.
5. There is a selection of the sign of the root of second degree in the denominator that has to be treated. The denominator can not be zero for real $x$ and $y'$ as long as the given selection of the sign of the root is taken.
6. There is a form of the given differential equation where $f(x,y,y')==0$:

   y'[x] ==
   Piecewise[{
   {(4 x y[x] - Sqrt[3 x^4 + 4 x^2 y[x]^2])/(x^2 - 4 y[x]^2), x < 0}},
   (4 x y[x] + Sqrt[3 x^4 + 4 x^2 y[x]^2])/(x^2 - 4 y[x]^2)]

With this we know different facts about what Mathematica can do for us!

A. Solution is possible with [`DSolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DSolve.html)! DSolve solves  a differential equation for the function u, with independent variable $x$ for $x$ between `Subscript[x, min]` and `Subscript[x, max]`.
B. We do not need NDSolve at all.
C. Because the functional dependence is steady and differentiable on the given interval the solution has this properties on the intervall too.

From the question there is one problem open for the proper solution. What are $x_min$ and $x_max$?

From the solution of DSolve:

```
sol = DSolve[{-x == y'[x] y[x]/(1 + Sqrt[1 + (y'[x])^2]/2), 
   y[0] == 3}, y, x]
```

[image]

(*{{y -> Function[{x}, Sqrt[5 - x^2 + 2 Sqrt[4 - x^2]]]}, {y ->
Function[{x}, Sqrt[45 - x^2 - 6 Sqrt[36 - x^2]]]}}*)

We get the information that the solutions are not restricted to a solution domain. With the original differential equation as input we get the information that `DSolve` invokes the methodology built-in Mathematica for calculating an inverse function of the differential equation. Therefore it invokes [`Reduce`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Reduce.html). The output does not include any of the results from `Reduce`.

These are message generated to stopp further such messages as before in the intermediate message output cue. At last it finds the "workaround" #3 from [@michael-e2](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/4999/michael-e2) but that is built-in process and not a "workaround" otherwise the solution set would be empty.

So what limits the solution for a domain is the selection shown by [@bob-hanlon](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/9362/bob-hanlon) by using [`FunctionDomain`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FunctionDomain.html). `FunctionDomain` restricts to `Reals`. That is not given in the question. And NDSolve would not restrict the solution methods to `Reals`. As my introductory picture shows up there no problem with the first solution.

We are in need of some geometric considerations. The given differential equation, a nonlinear one, describes shiftes ellipses and only the boundary of them. So the branches shown by [@bob-hanlon](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/9362/bob-hanlon) outside the by restriction to `Reals` appearing is not correct any more. Ellipsises are not infinitely extended.

The solution has to be treated further untill an evaluation is made sensible. The requirement by mathemtics is to get the roots away of the description. We do not want inversion for $x(y)$. There are many decription for ellipsises out there in Mathematics.

The solutions:

```
GraphicsGrid[{{Graphics[Circle[{0, 0}, {2, 3}], Axes -> True, 
    PlotRange -> {{-6, 6}, {-3.1, 3.1}}], 
   Graphics[Circle[{0, 0}, {5.2, 3}], Axes -> True, 
    PlotRange -> {{-6, 6}, {-3.1, 3.1}}]}}]
```

[image: the two ellipsis that represent the solution]

Why do we have this?
OK. This is due to the nonlinearity of the differential equation and the the differential equation itself is `Reals`. $x(0)==3$ fixes the ellipsis completely. There is only one parameter free to be solved. Mathematica calculates it by using `Reduce`. We can do this be hand as shown by another answer. That is what is necessary.

This step is as complicated as to accept that Mathematica classifies as I did explicitly internaly the differential equation in [`NDSolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NDSolve.html). The solution methodology hand the differential equation solution process to [`DSolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DSolve.html) and than interpolated the solution taken from this process and outputs that. This is a special case of laze evaluation. So my answer is not solving this with [`DSolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DSolve.html) but with [`NDSolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NDSolve.html) instead but using the head leaded path.

The difficulies are not resolved that way. The importance of the "workaround" #3 from [@michael-e2](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/4999/michael-e2) against all of his other workaround can be reinvented by finishing the path to the complete solution of the ellipsises out and accepting as the complete solution and the mathematical on true solution and the half-way solution all the others offer here. Do this by hand is hard work and a lot writing. Doing this the Mathematica process is not finishing the mathematical task complete and correct. It does simply not take track of the work [`Reduce`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Reduce.html) does.

But keep as the quint essence of the answer avoid roots in results fron Mathematica in most cases in the way that they should not appear in Your answer is close to a correct solution. Therefore it might be sensible to treat in [`Reduce`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Reduce.html) $y$ and $y'$ as independent and enter them adequately. There is no built-in for doing the work of transfering the work [`Reduce`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Reduce.html) does for You on the solution from Mathematica output. This is a matter of experience each Mathematician can to achieve. As shown by the answer of [@michael-e2](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/4999/michael-e2) it can be lead to new branches of solutions mixing all signs of roots up. Therefore the final solution is only unique is there is no ambivalent sign left out in front of roots.

Comment: Mathem. can treat implicit differential eqn's very well. The problem here is an issue with `Solve` which is usually called within `NDSolve`. The same bug does occur in `DSolve` as shown here: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/235185/incorrect-result-by-dsolve