# Incorrect result by DSolve

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, calculus-and-analysis, bugs, logic

For real $x$ consider the trivial equation
$$|y'(x)|=-|x|.$$
Since the left side is always positive and the right always negative, there is **no solution**.
Let's try

```
DSolve[Abs[y'[x]]==-Abs[x], y, x, Assumptions-> {x ∈ Reals}],

DSolve[Abs[y'[x]]==-RealAbs[x], y, x, Assumptions-> {x ∈ Reals}]
```

and

```
DSolve[Sqrt[y'[x]^2]==-Abs[x], y, x, Assumptions-> {x ∈ Reals}]
```

all giving the **wrong result**

```
{{y->Function[{x},Sign[x]/2 x^2+Subscript[\[ConstantC], 1]]},{y->Function[{x},-Sign[x]/2 x^2+Subscript[\[ConstantC], 1]]}}
```

At least

```
DSolve[RealAbs[y'[x]]==-RealAbs[x], y, x, Assumptions-> {x ∈ Reals}]
```

does return `{}`.

Is this a bug or a feature?

*Note that this is just one example. In any case when the equation is $f(y'(x))=...$ and $f$ contains square root or absolute value the results are wrong.*

**Edit:** Originally, the equation $|y'(x)|=-e^x$ was used for the example, but as a user found out, in that particluar case there is a complex solution.

Comment: `Abs` is a complex function which relate to  `z*Conjugate[z]`

Comment: `Sqrt` is also a complex function.

Comment: Almost all functions in mathematica can be used with complex argument. That would come into play if he considers $y$ to be complex.

Comment: As the results are wrong on every domain its not a problem of 'complex' calculation.

Comment: @fwgb Please, consider submitting a [bug report to WRI](https://support.wolfram.com/12507). (Or [here](https://www.wolfram.com/support/contact/email/?topic=Feedback).)

Comment: @AntonAntonov I reportet dozens of bugs over the years and got good feedback from WR. Just wanted to make sure it is one.

Comment: FWIW, the solutions are valid for `x == t + I*Pi` etc. where `t` ranges over the reals.  I would remark that assumptions are not restrictions, and that an assumption $P$ being false does not invalidate $P \Rightarrow Q$.  In the last example, the domain for `RealAbs` is restricted to the `Reals`.

Comment: @MichaelE2 No, the results are not valid for `x=t+I*Pi`. Since `Abs[Exp[t+I*Pi]]=Exp[t] != -Exp[t]`.

Comment: No, you should not compare `Exp[t]` with `-Exp[t]`, but with `-Exp[x]`. Try `Abs[y'[x]] == -Exp[x] /. sol /. x -> t + I*Pi // Simplify[#, t \[Element] Reals] &` or `Reduce[Abs[y'[x]] == -Exp[x] /. sol, x]`.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Okay, my bad. Ignoring the assumptions this equation can be rescued. But, the even simpler equation `Abs[y'[x]]== - Abs[x]` cannot be rescued by complex numbers.

Comment: Yes, quite. The source of the problem is with `Solve` more so than `DSolve`: `Solve[Abs[y'[x]] == -Abs[x] /. y'[x] -> yp, yp]`.

Comment: Agree, `Solve` causes the same problems here: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/235095/ndsolve-giving-a-wrong-solution