# What makes a system be differential-algebraic equations?

Tags: differential-equations, warning-messages

I am trying to solve the equations in the following way:

```
ndsovletmin = 0.;
ndsolvetmax = 100.;
EoMphi := {phi''[t] + 3. H[t] phi'[t] + phi[t] == 0.};
EoMa := {a'[t] == a[t] H[t], 3. H[t]^2 == phi'[t]^2/2. + phi[t]^2/2., Ne'[t] == H[t]};
bbc := {a[ndsovletmin] == 1., Ne[ndsovletmin] == 0., 
        phi[ndsovletmin] == 2., phi'[ndsovletmin] == 0.};
sol = NDSolve[{EoMphi, EoMa, bbc}, {phi[t], phi'[t], a[t], Ne[t]}, {t,
  ndsovletmin, ndsolvetmax}];
```

It gets a warning `"NDSolve::pdord: Some of the functions have zero differential order, so the equations will be solved as a system of differential-algebraic equations."`. But if I do a redefinition `dphi[t] == phi'[t], ddphi[t] == dphi'[t]`, the warning disappears:

```
ndsovletmin = 0.;
ndsolvetmax = 100.;
EoMphi := {ddphi[t] + 3. H[t] dphi[t] + phi[t] == 0., 
           dphi[t] == phi'[t], ddphi[t] == dphi'[t]};
EoMa := {a'[t] == a[t] H[t], 3. H[t]^2 == dphi[t]^2/2. + phi[t]^2/2., Ne'[t] == H[t]};
bbc := {a[ndsovletmin] == 1., Ne[ndsovletmin] == 0., 
        phi[ndsovletmin] == 2., dphi[ndsovletmin] == 0.};
sol = NDSolve[{EoMphi, EoMa, bbc}, {phi[t], phi'[t], a[t], Ne[t]}, {t,
  ndsovletmin, ndsolvetmax}];
```

What's the difference?

[image]

Comment: You don't solve for `H[t]` from `H'[t]`. So `H[t]` has zero differential order. It seems that `H[t]` is positive. So try defining `H[t_] := Sqrt[(phi'[t]^2 + phi[t]^2)/6.];` outside your system and then just use `H[t]`. When I try that I get no errors or warnings with your original method. Check all this very carefully to try to make certain this is correct.

Comment: @Bill, I try what you say, but the warning still exist, I have edit my question and post the figure there.

Answer (score 2):

Both of the systems are DAE system, and `NDSolve` has used DAE solver to solve both of them. The difference is, in 2nd case, the system involves explicit algebraic equations `3. H[t]^2 == dphi[t]^2/2. + phi[t]^2/2.` and `ddphi[t] + 3. dphi[t] H[t] + phi[t] == 0.` so `NDSolve` detects it's a DAE system immediately, while in 1st case, though the system actually doesn't involve derivative of `H[t]`, it's not immediately obvious in `NDSolve`'s eyes, so it first trys to transform the system to the standard form of ODE system (see [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/158519/1871) for more discussion) and fails, thus spits out the `pdord` warning and turns to the DAE solver afterwards.

If one forces `NDSolve` to use a DAE solver by setting `SolveDelayed` option in the first case, the `pdord` warning no longer appears, and the resulting `"FunctionExpression"` won't change:

```
ndsovletmin = 0.;
ndsolvetmax = 100.;
EoMphi = {phi''[t] + 3. H[t] phi'[t] + phi[t] == 0.};
EoMa = {a'[t] == a[t] H[t], 3. H[t]^2 == phi'[t]^2/2. + phi[t]^2/2., Ne'[t] == H[t]};
bbc = {a[ndsovletmin] == 1., Ne[ndsovletmin] == 0., phi[ndsovletmin] == 2., 
   phi'[ndsovletmin] == 0.};
    
NDSolve`ProcessEquations[{EoMphi, EoMa, bbc}, {phi[t], phi'[t], a[t], Ne[t]}, {t, 
       ndsovletmin, ndsolvetmax}, SolveDelayed -> #][[1]]["NumericalFunction"][
   "FunctionExpression"] & /@ {Automatic, True}
Function[func, 
  Function @@ {func[[2]] /. Thread[func[[1]] -> (Slot /@ Range@Length@func[[1]])]}] /@ %
```

> ```
> (*
> {{0. + #5 + 3. #3 #6 + #11, -#2 #3 + #7, 
>   3. #3^2 - 0.5 #5^2 - 0.5 #6^2, -#6 + #10, -#3 + #9} &, 
>  {0. + #5 + 3. #3 #6 + #11, -#2 #3 + #7, 
>   3. #3^2 - 0.5 #5^2 - 0.5 #6^2, -#6 + #10, -#3 + #9} &}
>  *)
> ```

If one forces `NDSolve` to use ODE solver, it simply fails:

```
ndsovletmin = 0.;
ndsolvetmax = 100.;
EoMphi = {ddphi[t] + 3. H[t] dphi[t] + phi[t] == 0., dphi[t] == phi'[t], 
   ddphi[t] == dphi'[t]};
EoMa = {a'[t] == a[t] H[t], 3. H[t]^2 == dphi[t]^2/2. + phi[t]^2/2., Ne'[t] == H[t]};
bbc = {a[ndsovletmin] == 1., Ne[ndsovletmin] == 0., phi[ndsovletmin] == 2., 
   dphi[ndsovletmin] == 0.};

NDSolve[{EoMphi, EoMa, bbc}, {phi[t], phi'[t], a[t], Ne[t]}, {t,
    ndsovletmin, ndsolvetmax}, SolveDelayed -> False]
```

> ```
> (* Input returned *)
> ```

Also, it's easy to cheat `NDSolve` in 2nd case. Just add the same derivative term to both sides of the algebraic equations to create 2 *fake* ODEs:

```
ndsovletmin = 0.;
ndsolvetmax = 100.;
EoMphi = {dphi[t] == phi'[t], ddphi[t] == dphi'[t]};
EoMa = {a'[t] == a[t] H[t], Ne'[t] == H[t]};
bbc = {a[ndsovletmin] == 1., Ne[ndsovletmin] == 0., phi[ndsovletmin] == 2., 
   dphi[ndsovletmin] == 0.};

fakeODE = {a'[t] + ddphi[t] + 3. H[t] dphi[t] + phi[t] == a'[t] + 0., 
           a'[t] + 3. H[t]^2 == a'[t] + dphi[t]^2/2. + phi[t]^2/2.}

NDSolve[{EoMphi, EoMa, fakeODE, bbc}, {phi[t], phi'[t], a[t], Ne[t]}, {t,
    ndsovletmin, ndsolvetmax}]
```

> ```
> NDSolve::pdord
> ```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Too long for a comment.

I am worried about the `;,` I see in your second screenshot. Please do not follow `;` with `,`

I restart Mathematica so it forgets all previous assignments.

I type literally

```
ndsovletmin=0.;
ndsolvetmax=100.;
H[t_]:=Sqrt[(phi'[t]^2+phi[t]^2)/6.];
EoMphi={phi''[t]+3. H[t] phi'[t]+phi[t]==0.};
EoMa={a'[t]==a[t] H[t],Ne'[t]==H[t]};
bbc={a[ndsovletmin]==1.,Ne[ndsovletmin]==0.,phi[ndsovletmin]==2.,phi'[ndsovletmin]==0.};
sol=NDSolve[{EoMphi,EoMa,bbc},{phi[t],phi'[t],a[t],Ne[t]},{t,ndsovletmin,ndsolvetmax}]
```

and it returns

```
{{phi[t]->InterpolatingFunction[...],phi'[t]->InterpolatingFunction[...],
  a[t]->InterpolatingFunction[...],Ne[t]->InterpolatingFunction[...]}}
```

with no warnings or errors.

I worry that you solve for `phi'` instead of only solve for `phi` and then find the derivative of `phi` to give you `phi'` but perhaps your way will not cause serious errors.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.