# Warnings while solving a system of coupled differential equations

Tags: differential-equations, numerics, warning-messages

I have a system of differential equations, given by

```
h0 = 69529/1000; og = 664/1000; c = 3*h0^2 (og);   zfinal = 236/100; sigmas = 1;
C1 = -10;
V[z_] := c*(y[z])^C1 ;
Vp[z_] := c C1 y[z]^(-1 + C1);

Phi0 = 1; 
Phi0p = 0;
```

```
n = 32; m = 64;
Klein = NDSolve[{H[z]^2 ==   h0 ^2 (1 - og) (1 + z)^3  +   1/3*(  V[z]  +   1/2*(1 + z)^2 H[z]^2*y'[z]^2   -   H[z]^2 (1 + z)^2 y'[z]^2 ( 1/2*H'[z]^2 (1 + z)^2-Vp[z])) -  H[z]^4 (1 + z)^3 y'[z]^3 , -1/ 3*(1 + z) D[   (V[z] + 1/2 H[z]^2 (1 + z)^2 y'[z]^2 - H[z]^2 (1 + z)^2 y'[z]^2*(   1/2*H'[z]^2 (1 + z)^2-Vp[z] )) -  3*H[z]^4 (1 + z)^3*y'[z]^3   , z] +   H[z]^2 (1 + z)^2*
 y'[z]^2 (  1 - 2*( 1/2*H'[z]^2 (1 + z)^2-Vp[z] )) -  4 H[z]^2 (1 + z) y'[z] -  ( -H[z]^2 (1 + z) y'[z]  +   H[z] (1 + z)*(y''[z]*H[z]*(1 + z) +    y'[z] (  H'[z] (1 + z) + H[z]))) == 0, H[0] == h0,   y[0] == Phi0, y'[0] == Phi0p}, {H, y}, {z, 0, zfinal},  PrecisionGoal -> n, AccuracyGoal -> n, WorkingPrecision -> m,  Method -> "StiffnessSwitching"];


Plot[Evaluate[H[z] /. Klein], {z, 0, zfinal}, PlotRange -> All]
```

If I evaluate the code I get the following warnings:

```
NDSolve::ntdvdae: Cannot solve to find an explicit formula for the derivatives. NDSolve will try solving the system as differential-algebraic equations.

NDSolve::nodae: The method NDSolve`StiffnessSwitching is not currently implemented to solve differential-algebraic equations. Use Method -> Automatic instead.

InterpolatingFunction::dmval: Input value {0.0000482114} lies outside the range of data in the interpolating function. Extrapolation will be used.
```

Is this normal? I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: Related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/158519/1871 Also, please make sure the equation system itself is correct.