# Numerically solving the KdV equation

Tags: differential-equations, compatibility, backslide

**Backslide introduced in 9, persisting through 13.**

---

I am trying to solve the KdV equation numerically. The following code would work perfectly in version 5:

```
q[x_] = (Erf[x] - 1)/2 - 5 Sech[x - 1]; xmax = 300; tmax = 10;

NDSolve[{D[u[x, t], t] == -D[u[x, t], x, x, x] + 6 u[x, t] D[u[x, t], x], 
u[x,0] == q[x], u[-xmax, t] == -1, u[xmax, t] == 0, 
Derivative[1, 0][u][-xmax, t] == 0, Derivative[1, 0][u][xmax, t] == 0}, 
u, {t, 0, tmax}, {x, -xmax, xmax}, Method -> StiffnessSwitching]
```

but fails in 12.3.0 for Mac with the error:

> At t==1.57.., stepsize is effectively zero

Obviously the method used by *Mathematica* produces oscillations on the positive half-axis, which should not be there. Any hints on how to get a valid numerical solution with *Mathematica*? Thanks.

Comment: I just noticed the problem is essentially caused by a design change of `NDSolve` so I added the tag [tag:compatibility], see the new-added link in my answer for more info.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Another problem related to conservation law. Based on the experience obtained in e.g. [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/230431/1871), let's avoid symbolic expansion of `D`. I'll use [`pdetoode`](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/127997/1871) for the task.

```
q[x_] = (Erf[x] - 1)/2 - 5 Sech[x - 1]; 
xmax = 300; tmax = 15;

With[{u = u[x, t], mid = mid[x, t]}, 
  eq = {D[u, t] == D[mid, x], mid == -D[u, x, x] + 3 u^2}];
ic = u[x, 0] == q[x];

points = 1500; difforder = 2; domain = {-xmax, xmax}; 
grid = Array[# &, points, domain];
(* Definition of pdetoode isn't included in this post,
   please find it in the link above. *)
ptoofunc = pdetoode[{u, mid}[x, t], t, grid, difforder];
odeadd = ptoofunc /@ eq[[2]];
ode = Block[{mid}, Set @@ odeadd; eq[[1]] // ptoofunc];

odeic = ptoofunc@ic;
sollst = NDSolveValue[{ode, odeic}, u /@ grid, {t, 0, tmax}]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {34.3459, Null} *)

sol = rebuild[sollst, grid, 2]; // AbsoluteTiming

rstlst = Plot[sol[x, #] // Evaluate, {x, -xmax, xmax}, PlotRange -> {-8, 1}, 
      PlotPoints -> 50] & /@ Range[0, tmax, 0.5]; // AbsoluteTiming

ListAnimate[rstlst, ControlPlacement -> Top]
```

[image]

```
DensityPlot[sol[x, t] // Evaluate, {x, -xmax, xmax}, {t, 0, tmax}, PlotPoints -> 200, 
 PlotRange -> All, ColorFunction -> Function[z, ColorData["AvocadoColors"][1 - z]]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Oh, I didn't set the boundary conditions, but given the solution is localized i.e. there's no interaction between boundary and solution, this should not be too big a problem.

Increasing `points` to `2000` doesn't significantly change the solution, and the result is consistent with that of *v5.2*:

[image]

So I guess the solution is reliable.

---

I tested the sample in other versions, and found the backslide is introduced in *v9*:

***v9.0.1***
[image]
***v8.0.4***
[image]

Further check shows `NDSolve` has used `9615` grid points in *v5.2*, and `9681` in *v8.0.4* for spatial discretization, thus this seems to be a backslide of priori error estimates.

> **Remark**
>
> Even further check shows `NDSolve` has used 2-norm instead of
> infinity-norm for priori error estimates since *v9*, see [this
> post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/274214/1871) for more
> info.

If we set the `Method -> {"MethodOfLines", "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", "MaxPoints" -> 9615, "MinPoints" -> 9615, "DifferenceOrder" -> 4}, Method -> "StiffnessSwitching"}` in higher versions:

[image]

`NDSolve` gives the desired result. Notice `Method -> "StiffnessSwitching"` is necessary here.

But still, my method that takes the consevation law into consideration is cheaper. (Only `1500` grid points are needed. )

Comment: I have decided to accept this solution, since it is much faster and the result coincides with some alternative code from Baumann I have found. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

Manually specifying a Method ("MethodOfLines") with a minimum spatial discretization works (and you have to increase the maximum number of allowed steps).

Also, use your `q[x]` to define the boundary conditions or they're getting invalid for smaller `xmax`.
This is especially true, since `xmax=300` is too much for this problem apparently. (At least for me looking at the produced solution)

```
q[x_]=(Erf[x]-1)/2-5 Sech[x-1];
xmax=300;tmax=10;

sol=NDSolve[{
    D[u[x,t],t]==-D[u[x,t],x,x,x]+6 u[x,t] D[u[x,t],x],
    u[x,0]==q[x],
    u[-xmax,t]==q[-xmax],
    u[xmax,t]==q[xmax],
    Derivative[1,0][u][-xmax,t]==D[q[x],x]/.x->-xmax,
    Derivative[1,0][u][xmax,t]==D[q[x],x]/.x->xmax
},u,{t,0,tmax},{x,-xmax,xmax},
Method->{"MethodOfLines","SpatialDiscretization"->{"TensorProductGrid","MinPoints"->10000}},
MaxSteps->100000
]
```

Plotting this with

```
soln=First[u/.sol]
DensityPlot[soln[x,t],{x,-xmax,xmax},{t,0,tmax},PlotRange->All,PlotPoints->300,MaxRecursion->1]
```

yields the following plot:

[image: Solution Density Plot]

You can always increase the spatial discretization to increase the resulting resolution.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Lack of resolutions was indeed the issue (+1).  `Plot3D[First[u /. sol][x, t], {x, -200, 200}, {t, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> All, PlotPoints -> 300, ViewPoint -> {0, -2.4`, 1}]` gives a striking visual.

Comment: Since this problem solved by increasing the spatial discretization, I am wondering maybe it can be also solved by finite element method using small enough cell size?

Comment: @xinxinguo No, currently FEM can only handle PDE whose differential order is no more than 2: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/199369/1871

Comment: @xzczd thanks, I didn't know that. :)

Comment: @bbgodfrey I obtain a similar solution but the amplitude isn't exactly the same. See my answer.

Comment: @xzczd How different is the amplitude and to what do you attribute it?  In any case, +1.

Comment: @bbgodfrey In _v12.3.1_, lowest valley in Julien's solution is around `-2.5`, while mine is around `-7`. Still, I suspect it's because naive spatial discretization won't work well on the problem. But who knows, perhaps neither of us is correct.

Comment: Thanks to both of you for your help! I don't see much difference in height, but there seems a shift between both solutions. It looks like the NDSolve solution is ahead of the pdetoode solution. I doubled the points with pdetoode and (visually) there is no difference, while the NDSolve solution is even further ahead. I also compared with some code from Baumann "Mathematica In Theoretical Physics". And this seems to match perfectly with what pdetoode produces.

Comment: @gerald and bbgodfrey, Oops, sorry… seems that I forgot to adjust `PlotRange` option when checking Julien's solution… Yes, the heights of our solutions are similar.