# Solution from NDSolve doesn't conserve a quantity that should be conserved

Tags: differential-equations, finite-element-method

I am trying to solve Klein-Gordon equation : $$(\frac{\partial^2}{\partial t^2}-\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}+1)\psi(x,t)=0$$
in a new coordinate system where $x\to y=\frac{x}{L(t)}$.

Here is my code :

```
ydum1 = x/L1[t];
expr1 = 1/c^2 D[ψ[ydum1, t], {t, 2}] - 
     D[ψ[ydum1, t], {x, 2}] + (m^2 c^2)/
      h^2 ψ[ydum1, t] /. ψ[ydum1, t] -> ψ[y, t] /. 
   x -> y L1[t] // Expand
m = 1;
c = 1;
h = 1;
ω1 = 1;
L1[t_] := 2 + Sin[ω1 t];
ic = {ψ[y, 0] == 
   Sqrt[2 (m c)/(c Sqrt[m^2 c^2 + π^2 h^2/L1[0]^2] L1[0])]
     Sin[ π y], 
  D[ψ[y, t], 
     t] == (-y L1'[t]/
       L1[t] D[Sqrt[
         2 (m c)/(c Sqrt[m^2 c^2 + π^2 h^2/L1[t]^2] L1[t])]
          Sin[ π y] Exp[-I c Sqrt[m^2 c^2 + π^2 h^2/L1[t]^2]
            t], y] + 
      D[Sqrt[2 (m c)/(c Sqrt[m^2 c^2 + π^2 h^2/L1[t]^2] L1[t])]
         Sin[ π y] Exp[-I c Sqrt[m^2 c^2 + π^2 h^2/L1[t]^2]
           t], t]) /. t -> 0};
sol1 = NDSolveValue[{expr1 == 0, 
   DirichletCondition[ψ[y, t] == 0, y >= 1], ψ[0, t] == 0, 
   ic}, ψ, {y, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 10}]
```

Turning back to $(x,t)$ coordinate :

```
xsol1 = {x, t} \[Function] sol1[x/L1[t], t];
```

Now I am going to define `charge density` : $J^0(x,t) = -\frac{i}{2}(\psi^*\frac{\partial \psi}{\partial t}-\frac{\partial \psi^*}{\partial t}\psi)$

```
xsolC = Conjugate@*xsol1;
dxsol = Derivative[0, 1][xsol1];
dxsolC = Conjugate@*dxsol;
J0 = -I/2 (xsolC[#1, #2] dxsol[#1, #2] - 
      dxsolC[#1, #2] xsol1[#1, #2]) &;
```

The `charge` $\int_0^{L1(t)} J^0(x,t) dx =\int_0^{L1(t)}-\frac{i}{2}(\psi^*\frac{\partial \psi}{\partial t}-\frac{\partial \psi^*}{\partial t}\psi) dx$ is a conserved quantity. However, when I plot integral (I am going to do the integral manually because I don't know how to integrate `J0` with code) :

```
n = 300;
result = 
  Table[Last@Accumulate[Array[1/n Abs@J0[#, t] &, n, {0, L1[t]}]], {t,
     0, 10, 10/n}];
ListPlot[result]
```

[image]

This value is far from conserved. I am guessing that the problem lies in the fact that $J^0(x,t) = -\frac{i}{2}(\psi^*\frac{\partial \psi}{\partial t}-\frac{\partial \psi^*}{\partial t}\psi)$ involves multiplication of 2 quantities that come from the numerical solution. So the small error in the numerical solution is magnified.

e.g.
$(\text{sol} + \text{error})(\text{sol} + \text{error}) = 2\text{sol}(\text{error}) + ...$ The error is magnified by the solution.

Is there anyway I can fix this?

**Reference**
Taken from Modern Quantum Mechanics by J.J. Sakurai 2nd ed., page 490
[image]

I did make a mistake by having an extra overall minus sign, but this shouldn't affect conservation of the quantity.

I further provide proof that the `charge` is indeed conserved :
[image]

**-----EDIT-----**

I have tested this on a simpler problem where analytical solution is easily achievable in order to trace the error. You can look up the analytical solution from equation 3.41 in the following paper http://i-rep.emu.edu.tr:8080/xmlui/bitstream/handle/11129/1302/SulaimanRafea.pdf?sequence=1. I am going to pick the solution with negative exponential sign.

```
ϕ[x_, t_] := Sqrt[2/en] Sin[π x] Exp[-I en t];
ϕc[x_, t_] := Sqrt[2/en] Sin[π x] Exp[I en t];
j = -I (ϕc[x, t] D[ϕ[x, t], t] - 
    D[ϕc[x, t], t] ϕ[x, t])
```

Output:

```
-4 Sin[π x]^2
```

`j` is clearly conserved since it's time independent.

**Numerical treatment :** The equation along with its b.c. and i.c. is written in the following  code :

```
kge = 1/c^2 D[ψ[x, t], {t, 2}] - 
   D[ψ[x, t], {x, 2}] + ψ[x, t];
ic = {ψ[x, 0] == Sqrt[2/Sqrt[1 + π^2]] Sin[ π x], 
  D[ψ[x, t], t] == 
    D[Sqrt[2/Sqrt[1 + π^2]]
       Sin[ π x] Exp[-I Sqrt[1 + π^2] t], t] /. t -> 0}
ss = NDSolveValue[{kge == 0, 
   DirichletCondition[ψ[x, t] == 0, x >= 1], ψ[0, t] == 0, 
   ic}, ψ, {x, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 10}]
```

Define `charge density`, `J` :

```
ssC = Conjugate@*ss;
dss = Derivative[0, 1][ss];
dssC = Conjugate@*dss;
J = -I/2 (ssC[#1, #2] dss[#1, #2] - dssC[#1, #2] ss[#1, #2]) &;
```

I am going to plot the `charge` (integral of `J` over all space)

```
n = 200;
λ = 
  Table[Last@Accumulate[Array[1/n Abs@J[#, t] &, n, {0, 1}]], {t, 0, 
    1, 1/n}];
ListPlot[λ]
```

[image]

And it's not conserved.

I am going to compare analytical and numerical solutions by plotting

```
Manipulate[
 Plot[{Re@ss[x, t], Re@ϕ[x, t]}, {x, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> {-1, 1},
   PlotLegends -> {"Numerical", "Analytical"}], {t, 0, 10}]
```

[image]

Although the numerical solution matches pretty well with the analytical one, the numerical solution kind of "jerks" as it move in time, which affects its time derivative.

```
Plot[Re@dss[0.5, t], {t, 0, 10}]
```

[image]

Since the `charge density` takes into account the time derivative $J^0(x,t) = -\frac{i}{2}(\psi^*\frac{\partial \psi}{\partial t}-\frac{\partial \psi^*}{\partial t}\psi)$, this is probably what has caused the error such that the `charge` is not conserved. I would greatly appreciate it if anyone can help me fix this.

**-----EDIT 2-----**

Back to the original problem with `TensorProductGrid` method :

```
ic2 = {\[Psi][y, 0] == 
    Sqrt[2 (m c)/(c Sqrt[m^2 c^2 + \[Pi]^2 h^2/L1[0]^2] L1[0])]
      Sin[ \[Pi] y], 
   D[\[Psi][y, t], t] == -I Sqrt[1 + \[Pi]^2/4] Sqrt[1/Sqrt[
      1 + \[Pi]^2/4]] Sin[\[Pi] y] /. t -> 0};
sol1 = NDSolveValue[{expr1 == 
    0, \[Psi][x, t] == 0 /. {{x -> 0}, {x -> 1}}, ic2}, \[Psi], {y, 0,
    1}, {t, 0, 10}]
```

I receive warning :

NDSolveValue::eerr: Warning: scaled local spatial error estimate of 41.164657086731026 `at t = 10.` in the direction of independent variable y is much greater than the prescribed error tolerance. Grid spacing with 25 points may be too large to achieve the desired accuracy or precision. A singularity may have formed or a smaller grid spacing can be specified using the MaxStepSize or MinPoints method options.

```
Plot3D[{Re@sol1[y, t], Im@sol1[y, t]}, {y, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 10}, 
 AxesLabel -> {y, t, \[Psi]}, PlotRange -> {-1, 1}, 
 PlotLabel -> "Wavefunction \[Psi](y,t)", 
 PlotLegends -> {"Real", "Im"}]
```

[image]

And unfortunately the solution goes wild at later time. The fact that `NDSolveValue` evaluates beyond `y=1` is suspicious to me, which was why I added `DirichletCondition[ψ[y, t] == 0, y >= 1]` before.

```
Manipulate[
 Plot[{Re@sol1[y, t], Im@sol1[y, t]}, {y, 0, 2}, 
  PlotLabel -> "Wavefunction \[Psi](y,t)", 
  PlotRange -> {{0, 2}, {-1.5, 1.5}}, 
  PlotLegends -> {"Real", "Im"}], {t, 0, 10}]
```

[image]

Any kind of help is much appreciated.

Comment: What happens if you decrease the max step size?

Comment: Are you sure the formula for charge density is correct? Can you add a reference or something?

Comment: Echoing the previous comment of @xzczd - are you sure you should have partial derivatives w.r.t. t there and instead they should be x.

Comment: @user21, by max step size, do you mean the `n` in my code? I have tried varying it but the shape of the curve that I get doesn't change.

@xzczd, @1729taxi, Yes, the formula is correct (except for an overall minus sign), I have provided a reference in the question above.

Comment: MaxStepSize is an option for NDSolve.

Comment: I'm in a hurry at the moment so cannot check, but to make the numeric solution respect conservation law, we might need to start from equation from p3 here: https://www.hep.phy.cam.ac.uk/theory/webber/GFT/gft_handout2_06.pdf Somewhat related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/262173/1871

Comment: @user21, I have tried setting it to `1`, but the problem persists.
@xzczd, Thanks for the links. I have tried plotting the 2nd eqn of p3 from the first link (which essentially says derivative j0 w.r.t. t minus derivative j1 w.r.t. x equals 0)and the result is of order `10^-7` so it's considered conserved. However, the quantity that I am interested in conserving is the `charge`, defined at the integral of j0 w.r.t. x over the entire space (which is 0<x<L in this problem). I have shown in my last picture that this quantity should be conserved.

Comment: You've boiled down the problem nicely. Seems that something is wrong with `FiniteElement` method. With the old good `TensorProductGrid` the charge conserves: `ss=NDSolveValue[{kge==0, ψ[x, t]==0 /. {{x -> 0}, {x -> 1}}, ic}, ψ, {x, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 10}];ssC = Conjugate@*ss;dss = Derivative[0, 1][ss];dssC = Conjugate@*dss; J=-I/2(ssC[#, #2] dss[#, #2] - dssC[#,#2] ss[#,#2]) &; ListPlot[Table[NIntegrate[Abs@J[x, t], {x, 0, 1}], {t, 0, 1, 1/20}]]` This isn't the end, there seems to be another bug related to `NIntegrate`, I started a new question: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/264186/1871

Comment: With `Method -> {"MethodOfLines", "SpatialDiscretization" -> "FiniteElement"}, MaxStepSize -> 10^-3` The FEM solution will be much better, but still not comparable to that of `TensorProductGrid`.

Comment: @ForacleFunacle You mixed up the problem of charge saving in space-time and particular problem of saving  charge in your space with $y=x/L(t)$. There is no theorem about last case. Your proof that $dj_0/dt=0$ is wrong since $\psi=\psi(x/L(t),t)$ and you did not pay attention on this.

Comment: @AlexTrounev, but I did change back to $(x,t)$ coordinate before defining my charge density in the code. I also tried to derive this proof in $(y,t)$ coordinate, where $\frac{d}{dt}=\frac{\partial y}{\partial t} \frac{\partial}{\partial y}+\frac{\partial}{\partial t}$. It beautifully ended up into $\frac{dj_0}{dt}=\frac{1}{L^2(t)}(\psi^*\frac{\partial^2 \psi}{\partial y^2}-\frac{\partial^2 \psi^*}{\partial y^2}\psi)$. And from here, proceed with integration by parts just like in $(x,t)$ coordinate to show that this reduces to 0.

Comment: @xzczd, Thanks a lot for the help! However, when I tried to use `TensorProductGrid` method, I receive a warning and the solution is kind of absurd (check out edit 2 in my question). Do you have any suggestion for this?

Comment: @ForacleFunacle Just put `\psi= f[x/L[t], t] + I g[x/L[t], t]` with real `f, g` and run your computations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, since both `FiniteElement` and `TensorProductGrid` are not good at handling the problem, let me show a solution using [`pdetoode`](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/127997/1871):

```
(* Definition of expr1 and ic2 are the same as yours. *)
bc = ψ[x, t] == 0 /. {{x -> 0}, {x -> 1}};

domain = {0, 1}; points = 25; difforder = 2;
grid = Array[# &, points, domain];

(* Definition of pdetoode isn't included in this post,
   please find it in the link above. *)
ptoofunc = pdetoode[ψ[y, t], t, grid, difforder];
del = #[[2 ;; -2]] &;
ode = del@ptoofunc[expr1 == 0];
odeic = ptoofunc@ic2;
odebc = With[{sf = 0}, ptoofunc@diffbc[{t, 2}, sf]@bc];
sollst = NDSolveValue[{ode, odeic, odebc}, ψ /@ grid, 
                      {t, 0, 10}]; // AbsoluteTiming

solmid = rebuild[sollst, grid, 2];
sol = {x, t} |-> solmid[x/L1[t], t];

reg = DiscretizeRegion@ImplicitRegion[0 < t < 5 && 0 < x/L1[t] < 1, {x, t}]

Plot3D[{Re@sol[x, t], Im@sol[x, t]}, {x, t} ∈ reg, AxesLabel -> {x, t, ψ}, 
 PlotRange -> All, PlotLabel -> "Wavefunction ψ(x,t)", 
 PlotLegends -> Placed[{"Real", "Im"}, {After, Center}], PlotPoints -> 100]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
solc = Conjugate@*sol;
dsol = Derivative[0, 1][sol];
dsolc = Conjugate@*dsol;
J0 = -I/2 (solc[#1, #2] dsol[#1, #2] - dsolc[#1, #2] sol[#1, #2]) &;
help[x_?NumericQ, t_] := Abs@J0[x, t]
ListPlot[Quiet@
  Table[NIntegrate[help[x, t], {x, 0, L1[t]}, 
    Method -> {Automatic, SymbolicProcessing -> 0}], {t, 0, 1, 1/20}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The conservation will be better if you make `points` larger.

Comment: Now everything runs perfectly, can't thank you enough!! I have some questions, what is the `odebc` for? I saw in your other post you have set `sf=100`, what is this quantity?

Comment: @ForacleFunacle I've discussed this in detail in this post: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/127411/1871 In short, `sf` is amount to `"ScaleFactor"` sub-option of `NDSolve`. Since the i.c.s and b.c.s are consistent in your case, we can set it to `0`. Notice  `odebc` together with `odeic[[All, {1, -1}]]` is equivalent to `bc`.