# NIntegrate can't handle InterpolatingFunction produced by FiniteElement properly?

Tags: differential-equations, bugs, complex, finite-element-method, interpolation

**Bug introduced in 12.3.1 or earlier and fixed in 13.1.0**

---

This is a problem comes out in the discussion [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/264070/1871) and I think it's worth posting a new question for it. Consider the following sample:

```
With[{ψ = ψ[x, t]}, kge = D[ψ, {t, 2}] - D[ψ, {x, 2}] + ψ;
                    ic = {ψ == Sin[Pi x], D[ψ, t] == I Sin[π x]} /. t -> 0;
                    bc = ψ == 0 /. {{x -> 0}, {x -> 1}}];    
sol = NDSolveValue[{kge == 0, bc, ic}, ψ, {x, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 10}, 
   Method -> {MethodOfLines, SpatialDiscretization -> FiniteElement}];

dsol = Derivative[0, 1][sol];
J = sol[#1, #2] + dsol[#1, #2] &;

help[x_?NumericQ, t_] := Abs@J[x, t]
ListPlot[Quiet@Table[NIntegrate[help[x, t], {x, 0, 1}], {t, 0, 1, 1/20}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
ListPlot[Quiet@Table[NIntegrate[Abs@J[x, t], {x, 0, 1}], {t, 0, 1, 1/20}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Integration based on trapezoid rule suggests the first result is correct:

```
ListPlot[
  Table[With[{dh = 1/20}, 
    dh (Total@# - 1/2 (First@# - Last@#)) &@Table[Abs@J[x, t], {x, 0, 1, dh}]], 
       {t, 0, 1, 1/20}]]
```

Why doesn't `NIntegrate` work properly in 2nd case? Is `_?NumericQ` the only possible fix here?

Tested in *v12.3.1* and *v13.0.0* (Wolfram Cloud).

Comment: This looks like a bug, try to swap t and x. t first, x second. Is that what you expect. Also, increase the AccuracyGoal -> 8, PrecisionGoal -> 8 or reduce the MaxStepSize.

Comment: I have just merged a fix for this. The fix will be available in version 13.1. Thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 5):

This is a bad bug of NIntegrate. Both intergrations use the same data as you can see using EvaluationMonitor. Not to produce too many data I only integrate a small piece:

```
NIntegrate[help[x, 1], {x, 0, .001}, EvaluationMonitor :> Print[{x, help[x, 1]}]]
NIntegrate[Abs@J[x, 1], {x, 0, .001}, EvaluationMonitor :> Print[{x, Abs@J[x, 1]}]]
```

The output from EvaluationMonitor is the same in both cases:

[image]

However, the first result is 1.05095*10^-6 and the second: 2.66313*10^-6. It is easy to verify that the first is correct. Therefore, something must go wrong in adding up the pieces.

Please report this to support@wolfram.com

Comment: I doubt this is a bug in `NIntegrate`.

Comment: Please explain.

Comment: The interpolating function already returns wrong results.

Comment: In this case the EvaluationMonitor would not display the same values.

Comment: "Both intergrations use the same data…" This statement isn't accurate, I'm afraid. The expression in `EvaluationMonitor` is actually arbitrary. Try e.g. `NIntegrate[help[x, 1], {x, 0, .001}, EvaluationMonitor :> Print[{x, Abs@J[x, 1]}]]` or even `NIntegrate[help[x, 1], {x, 0, .001}, EvaluationMonitor :> Print[{x, Sin[x]}]]`. Of course in both cases `NIntegrate` has sampled at same `x`s, but this doesn't mean the integrands are the same.